# What is the difference between interrupt latency and interrupt response?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science, scheduling, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Everywhere I searched on Google has not provided me the answer I was looking for. In fact, most of them say they are used interchangeably.

My assignment has posed this question and I would really like to understand what the difference is. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interrupt latency is the time between the generation of the interrupt and when the processing of the interrupt *begins*. The term "interrupt response" is, unfortunately, used many different ways, but usually it is either talking about or including the time spent actually responding to the interrupt, which is what happens *after* the latency is completed.

Comment: Why do you think interrupt latency may be lower with a cooperative, non-preemptive kernel?

Comment: @BlaZinStAnG If interrupts don't pre-empt the kernel, you'd expect it to have more interrupt latency (unless it dedicates a core to servicing interrupts).

Answer (score 0):

It is the time interval between the processor recognising the interrupt to the time when the first instruction of the interrupt service routine is executed.this is determined by the processor architecture and clock speed.

Answer (score 0):

Interrupt latency refers to the time from signaling the cpu about the interrupt to the execution of the first routine to handle it. On the other hand, interrupt response time refers to the time from signaling the cpu about the interrupt to the completion of its execution.